# Server executables looking for wrong version of OpenSSL dll files

Tags: azerothcore

I've built and compiled in Windows and have OpenSSL 3.0 installed, when trying to run authserver.exe or worldserver.exe, I'm presented with the following errors:

---

### worldserver.exe - System Error

### The code execution cannot proceed because libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

### OK

---

### worldserver.exe - System Error

### The code execution cannot proceed because libssl-1_1-x64.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

### OK

Have I done something with the installation here? I'm not sure why it's looking for an older version of OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need OpenSSL version `1.0.x` as the official [software requirements page](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/windows-requirements) states.

Comment: OpenSSL 3.0 is fine.

Comment: This issue is probably that there's 2 versions installed on the system, with system variables for the older version. A fix would be to remove all OpenSSL installs, reinstall 3.0 and make sure the env vars and CMake settings point to the right version

Comment: @Kitzunu then that wiki is not up to date and should be fixed

Comment: "OpenSLL ≥ 1.0.x" greater or equal to. It is fine

Answer (score 2):

This issue is probably that there's 2 versions installed on the system, with system variables for the older version. Which causes you to compile with 1.1, but as you add the DLLs for 3.0 it will complain.

A fix would be to remove all OpenSSL installs, reinstall 3.0 and make sure the env vars and CMake settings point to the right version and then recompile the source